# Angular Material Table cannot read my response data

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am having an issue using [Angular Material Table with DataSource](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview).

**This is my HTML template:**

```
 <div>
<mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="created">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Created </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let film"> {{film.created}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="director">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Director </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let film"> {{film.director}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="edited">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edited </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let film"> {{film.edited}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="episode_id">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Episode ID</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let film"> {{film.episode_id}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row;columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```

**This is my service:**

```
  getFilms(): Observable<FilmModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<FilmModel[]>(`'http://localhost/api/getFilms');
  }
```

**This is my component trying to use DataSource from Angular Material:**

```
 import { Component } from '@angular/core';
 import { StarWarsService } from '../star-wars.service';
 import { DataSource } from '@angular/cdk/collections';
 import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
 import { FilmModel } from './film.model';

 @Component({
  selector: 'app-films',
  templateUrl: './films.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./films.component.css']
 })
 export class FilmsComponent {

   dataSource = new FilmDataSource(this.swService);

   displayedColumns = ['created', 'director', 'edited', 'episode_id'];

   constructor(private swService: StarWarsService) { }
 }

 export class FilmDataSource extends DataSource<any> {

   constructor(private swService: StarWarsService) {
    super();
   }

   connect(): Observable<FilmModel[]> {
     return this.swService.getFilms()
   }

   disconnect() {}
 }
```

**And this is the model entity:**

```
 export interface FilmModel {
  created: string;
  director: string;
  edited: string;
  episode_id: number;
  opening_crawl: string;
  producer: string;
  release_date: string;
  title: string;
  url: string;
}
```

**The error that I have every time it hit the getFilm service is:**

`Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed`

This is how looks the returned response from the API call:

```
 {
     count: 7,
     next: null,
     previous: null,
     results: [{...}]
 }
```

My guess will be that it is trying to apply the data source to an object while it is expecting an array so I can iterate tough the response.

How can I amend my code to read only `results` Array from the response data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the results from the data object, Change your service method as,

```
 return this.http.get<Project[]>(environment.apiRoot + 'projects/GetProjects').map(data => data.results);
```

Comment: I tried this solution and still get the same error about not using an Array.

Comment: try debugging what do you see in data.results